# Android Root View

Tags: android

What will this return `findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView()`? Will it return the rootview of my application or the rootview of the main screen in android?

Comment: [getRootView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getRootView()) Says **Finds the topmost view in the current view hierarchy.**

Answer (score 1):

> getRootView() Finds the topmost view in the current view hierarchy.

in http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Basically will return the "highest parent view" of the current screen you're seeing.

Comment: so what's your answer for "Will it return the rootview of my application or the rootview of the main screen"?

Comment: The rootview of your current screen. If that is your main screen, then it will be the rootview of your main screen. But that's kind of dubious since that could also be the root view of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the root view of your application.